# Как добавить модули в систему на YII2 через админку?

Tags: yii2

Прошу поделиться опытом,
интересует технология, по которой к системе на Yii2 через админку можно было бы подключать разные модули этой системы при необходимости.
То есть наверно нужен какой то скрипт, который бы прописывал в нужные файлы нужную информацию по модулю или система сама бы каким-то чудным образом увидела появившийся модуль и начала с ним работать?
Спасибо!

Comment: Как система сама должна начать с новым модулем работать? Откуда она узнает, что делать с этим модулем, если не будет нового кода.

Comment: например, прошерстить каталог modules и узнать что там лежит

Comment: Ну тогда та информация в ответе - то что вам нужно. Сейчас добавлю где конкретно глянуть.

Answer (score 1):

Могу посоветовать посмотреть на [Phundament](http://phundament.com) - это шаблон для yii2 приложений, если его развернуть, то там помимо всего прочего есть администраторский модуль, который показывает все загруженные модули на данный момент. Можно использовать или вдохновиться для создания своего, если он покажется вам слишком громоздким. Для отключения модулей я использую такой код:

```
Yii::$container->set('path\to\module\Bootstrap',function(){
    return new yii\base\Object(); // or new stdClass();
});
```

[Пример](https://github.com/phundament/app/tree/master/src/modules/backend) модуля админки.